# Creating, dragging and selecting some icons in a view

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, drag-and-drop, cocos2d-iphone

I've to start a new iOS project where I have to display a view with a background and then create some icons over the background.
Then, for each icon, I can:
- drag the icon in a different position of the screen
- select the icon and display a popup view with some options

My problem is to choose the best framework for this task: which framework do you suggest? 
OpenGL for iOS or COCOS2D ? Other hints?

Could you suggest me the best way ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the UIKit-Framework. You should have a look into `UIView`, `UIImage`, `UIImageView`, `CALayer`, `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:`. In Addition `UIGestureRecognizer` could help.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is related to the movement of the image . And what about the creation and animation of the sprite ? Thank you in advance...

Comment: With spite you mean the popup?